# What does that code "DetailActivity.ID to it.id" mean?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a beginner of Kotlin. The following code is from Kotlin-for-Android-Developers at

https://github.com/antoniolg/Kotlin-for-Android-Developers/blob/master-june-2017/app/src/main/java/com/antonioleiva/weatherapp/ui/activities/MainActivity.kt

The fun startActivity have two parameter `DetailActivity.ID to it.id` and `DetailActivity.CITY_NAME to result.city`.

Could you explain the details about the two parameters?

```
private fun loadForecast() = doAsync {
    val result = RequestForecastCommand(zipCode).execute()
    uiThread {
        val adapter = ForecastListAdapter(result) {
            startActivity<DetailActivity>(DetailActivity.ID to it.id,
                    DetailActivity.CITY_NAME to result.city)
        }
        forecastList.adapter = adapter
        toolbarTitle = "${result.city} (${result.country})"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`to`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) is an infix function in the standard library for creaing `Pair` instances easily.

`DetailActivity.ID to it.id` is equivalent to `Pair(DetailActivity.ID, it.id)`.

---

You can actually jump in to see its implementation by using `Ctrl + B` on it in Android Studio, it's pretty straightforward:

```
public infix fun <A, B> A.to(that: B): Pair<A, B> = Pair(this, that)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`to` is an infix function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) that creates a pair from to instances:

```
infix fun <A, B> A.to(that: B): Pair<A, B>
```

Instead of writing `val pair = Pair(a, b)`, you can now write `val pair = a to b`.